# Adding Generated Code (wsdl generated) as DataContracts and DataMembers for another WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asmx, datacontract

I have WCF project which calls another asmx webservice. When I added asmx webservice to wcf Project it generated some classes. Now I want to expose those classes as DataContract and DataMembers to my WCF service. I really want to achieve this with out much duplication.

Till now what I tried
When I added generated class as a property (DataMember) to existing DataContract, client which is calling WCF service see the members as **variableName**Field.  I really don't want to see these Field which are private variables But I want to see real properties.

WCF project Contract Looks like this

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Person
{

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

         [DataMember]
        public PersonPay PersonPay {get;set;}


}
```

wsdl generated code in wcf project from asmx web service wsdl

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
    public partial class PersonPay : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

     private double salaryField;

      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public bool Salary{
            get {
                return this.salaryField;
            }
            set {
                this.salaryField= value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Salary");
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use Text Template Transform Toolkit (T4 or ..tt files), for reading the ASMX generated files belonging to your project, recreate them the same way in another namespace with adding the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes

Regards

Comment: OK Praneeth, may be the best to remove noise, is you to edit your question to say you don't want code generation - then I delete my answer, don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your generated `PersonPay` class from ASMX are `[Serializable]`.

According to my WCF Guru, Juval Löwy, `PersonPay` should be serialized as they are to the WCF service.

Just give a try, and tell us.

Regards

Comment: I didn't understand. I can't removed serializable attribute because it is generated code

Comment: @Praneeth, just keep the generated code as it is. The PersonPay class should be Serializable by WCF Framework- now you ve got to try ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately Salary field is not shown in the client code. But I can see the  object itself.